# Vtc actuator replacement on honda

Tags: timing, pulley, actuator, crank

So I wanted to replace my vtc actuator because my car makes a grinding noise on start up I began taking the valve cover off and once I got it off I went to the crank pulley to rotate the motor I was able to align the cam sprockets but I couldn’t get the crank pulley to line up on the timing cover now the car ran perfectly fine before I did this job it’s just made a grinding noise on start up I think the crank pulley must of slipped a while ago it’s about a half inch advanced from the timing mark on the cover is it normal for a 2012 honda si crank pulley to slip the cars only 10 years old I mean the previous owner did drive the car a little hard , also would I be okay starting the engine back up , I didn’t touch any of the internals all I did was take the valve cover off and rotate the motor , could maybe the chain slipped as I rotated the engine over using the crank pulley ? I never removed any guides and never touched the tensioner just rotate everything forward once then noticed it wasnt lining up so I rotate the engine clockwise again and same thing the pulley was off a half inch while the cam sprocket lined up , my car doesn’t have any timing related engine codes and it ran good I’m just worried going to start it up again I’m nervous it might have a rough start cause as I rotated the motor over and oil cam out of the vvt sprocket

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you edit your question and please add some punctuation to it so we can understand what you're trying to ask?

Comment: And paragraphs too!  Currently, it's a WOT (Wall Of Text).